# Identify optimal thresholds for one-vs-one/one-vs-rest ROC-curve for multiclass classification

Tags: classification, multiclass-classification, roc

Say I have a multiclass classification problem with `N` classes.
I have trained a classifier on a training set, I use a validation set and a One-vs-rest ROC-curve to give me `N` ROC curves.

Since the ROC curve is created based on different thresholds of when we classify a sample as $Ci$ or not $Ci$. We can then chose (our) optimal FPR/TRP ratio and get the threshold (`t`) e.g say `t=0.6` we classify a sample as $Ci$ if `model_score>=0.6` else "the rest" i.e not $Ci$.
(the blue marker at this picture from sklearn)
[image]

The question is, in the multi-class problem we can use e.g one-vs-rest and create `N` ROC-curves (see below, also from sklearn)

[image]

*but* now we have `N` different thresholds (in the plot, `N=3` since we have three classes). Say we in the one-vs-rest have defined the optimal threshold for the classes as

```
t1 = 0.8 (Class 1 vs rest)
t2 = 0.6 (Class 2 vs rest)
t3 = 0.4 (class 3 vs rest)
```

we get a new sample and the model-score is `S= [0.3,0.4,0.3]` thus according to the thresholds we won't label it as any class since no score is above the threshold.

Comment: Please don't cross-post your question to multiple sites... https://stackoverflow.com/q/68405240/333599

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/147320

Comment: What are the costs of making the various kinds of mistakes, such as calling a $0$ a $2$ or calling a $1$ a $0?$

Comment: @Dave assume the misclassification-costs are all equal

Answer (score 1):

Without modifying the assumptions or the model, there are two choices:

1. The system returns the best single guess. For example, Class 2 since that is the best model's largest probability.
2. The system returns "Not confident enough to make a prediction".